# How do nested pages/mongoose schemas work? Getting errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am making a site that is a mock forum where the user clicks on a forum topic, goes to a unique .ejs page with forums, and then goes to another unique .ejs page where the forum is, where both pages are altered based on what the user fills into a Form on the previous page. The first step worked, but I keep getting either a TypeError "can't read property name of null" or a reference error (depending on what object info I type into the .ejs page) when I end up clicking on a link that would go from the "forum topic" page to the "forum". Data is being added to the database and I created corresponding mongoose schemas that are linked to each other and the main app so I'm not sure what the issue is.

I'm using this with express and mongodb/mongoose, the page that's getting the type error is a .ejs page. I'm assuming the main issue is in one of the routing blocks in the main app document, but it may not be and it may be some other concept or page configuration I'm not getting. What is the deal with nested schemas and pages for those who are more experienced with this?

Here is the page itself that has the error:

```
TypeError: /Users/roberts4/project_4/views/forum.ejs:4
    2| 
    3| <nav class = "container">
 >> 4|      <a href = "#">Welcome to Forum/ <%= forum.name %></a>
    5|      <a href = "#">Reply</a>
    6|      <a class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/main/<%= forumtopic._id 
       %>/<%= forum._id %>/reply/new">Add New Forum</a>
    7|  

 Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

The post function that you will see has has the "forum" created inside of the "forumtopic" id, unlike for what I did when posting the "forumtopic" itself.I tried adding req.body variables but it seems like that's only used if you're not posting them to a different page.

```
///there is code above this for forumtopic that's similar, except the 
////.post block has the .create by itself and not inside of .findById

app.get("/main/:id/forum", function(req, res){
    Forum.find({}, function(err, allForums){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("forumtopic", {forums: allForums});
        }
    })
});


app.post("/main/:id/forum", function(req, res){
  ForumTopic.findById(req.params.id, function(err, forumtopic){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/main");
    } else {
        //console.log(req,body.comment);
        Forum.create(req.body.forum, function(err, forum){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                forumtopic.forums.push(forum);
                forumtopic.save();
                res.redirect('/main/' + 
                                    forumtopic._id);
            }
        })
    }
})
});


app.get("/main/:id/forum/new", function(req, res){
     ForumTopic.findById(req.params.id, function(err, forumtopic){
        if(err){
        console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("newforum", {forumtopic: forumtopic});
        }
      })
});


app.get("/main/:id/:forumid", function(req, res) {

     Forum.findById(req.params.id).populate("replies").exec(function(err, 
     foundForum) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundForum);
            res.render("forum", {forum: foundForum});
        }
       })
 });

 ///there is code below this that's not accessed yet because of the error
```

Getting a TypeError 'cannot read property name of null', expecting 
a page that displays information based off of node in the app.js.

Comment: I do not see `name` anywhere in your code. On which line is the error thrown?

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant code in it.

Comment: All set, keep in mind there are also files that have the models with schemas in them, I don't think that's where the issue is but let me know if you want to see them

Comment: What does `console.log(foundForum);` line print?

Comment: It prints null, so forum is not being added to the db but the forumtopic was, but each forumtopic has forum titles inside of it with its ._id  and name

Comment: Do you get any error when your code hits the path `app.post("/main/:id/forum")`? This is where the forum should be added but it is not being added, correct?

Comment: I'm getting the error below it at app.get("/main/:id/:forumid"), if you were to look at the app, the forum name is being added to the forumtopic page but then the forum page won't load when you click on it

Comment: Are you sure `:id/:forumid` are not exchanged? You are finding a forum by id and you are passing `req.params.id`. Shouldn't it be `forumid`?

Comment: Ok so I changed it to that, and that particular error went away, but now I'm getting ReferenceError: forumtopic is not defined when I click on a forum.

Comment: Is the output of `console.log(foundForum);` still null? Add the line where you get the error message.

Comment: No it is not- the issue is mostly fixed now, thanks. What I will do now is change the link in another post block so that forumtopic won't impede the other link I put in the forum page